# source not reading symlink correctly?

Tags: bash, source

My `.bashrc` file is a symlink to `~/Scripts/rc/bashrc`. This works well for me, and has been for years.

However, as of today, this is what I am seeing:

```
bash-4.3$ source .bashrc
bash: source: .bashrc: file not found
bash-4.3$ ls -la .bashrc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jonas jonas 17 Oct 28 12:31 .bashrc -> Scripts/rc/bashrc
bash-4.3$ source Scripts/rc/bashrc 
jonas@jonas-xps:~$
```

I can't really make sense of this. Why would it suddenly stop working? I am using Utopic on a amd64 Dell laptop.

Some debug ouput:

```
bash-4.3$ stat .bashrc
  File: ‘.bashrc’ -> ‘Scripts/rc/bashrc’
  Size: 17          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 22h/34d Inode: 10880136    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1001/   jonas)   Gid: ( 1001/   jonas)
Access: 2014-10-28 12:31:57.076868217 +0100
Modify: 2014-10-28 12:31:57.076868217 +0100
Change: 2014-10-28 12:31:57.076868217 +0100
 Birth: -

bash-4.3$ stat Scripts/rc/bashrc
  File: ‘Scripts/rc/bashrc’
  Size: 4019        Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 22h/34d Inode: 11146383    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/   jonas)   Gid: ( 1001/   jonas)
Access: 2014-10-28 12:29:53.352871873 +0100
Modify: 2014-05-27 12:43:09.470849817 +0200
Change: 2014-05-27 12:43:09.470849817 +0200
 Birth: -

bash-4.3$ readlink -e .bashrc
/home/jonas/Scripts/rc/bashrc
```

Comment: Maybe try changing the linked file to a hidden file? `.bashrc`?

Comment: Strange indeed... please post the output of `stat .bashrc ` and `stat Scripts/rc/bashrc` and `readlink -e .bashrc`.

Comment: I have found the cause of this bug. I have an `rsync` task in Gnome Scheduler which when run causes this. A reboot fixes it. @Jan, do you see anything strange in the output? Anything I can use to file a bug against Gnome Scheduler?

Comment: What does the `rsync` do? Could it be removing the file and recreating it? Such a race condition might explain your symptoms. Also try running `strace bash -c "builtin . ~/.bashrc` that should show you exactly where the error is happening and why.

Comment: It pushes some unrelated files (deja-dup files) to a remote location. I doubt that's it.

Comment: Well, if you say that stopping the rsync changes the behavior, it kinds has to be it somehow. Did you try the `strace` I suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the filename does not contain a `/`, the builtin command `source` may look up the name in the `PATH` only, depending on some shell options. So instead of `source .bashrc`,

```
`source ./.bashrc`
```

should do what you want.

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):

```
     .  filename [arguments]
    source filename [arguments]
           Read  and  execute  commands from filename in the current shell
           environment and return the exit status of the last command exe‐
           cuted  from  filename.   If  filename does not contain a slash,
           filenames in PATH are used to  find  the  directory  containing
           filename.   The  file  searched  for  in  PATH need not be exe‐
           cutable.  When bash is not in posix mode, the current directory
           is  searched  if  no  file is found in PATH.  If the sourcepath
           option to the shopt builtin command is turned off, the PATH  is
           not  searched.
```

Comment: That works, thanks, but I'm running the `source` program indirectly by starting `gnome-terminal`. Should I change the `profile` file you mean? This does not answer why it suddenly changed, maybe you can speculate? My reasoning fall short.

Comment: It could have something to do with the recent Bash security problem named ShellShock. The security hole had to do with parsing indirect parameters which could be altered, the fix is to not longer allow this.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange As the man page says it depends on POSIX mode or not, a change in that may have changed it.

Comment: I don't know what POSIX mode is.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange it's what you get if you call `bash` as `sh` or launch it with the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable set.